# Is Ajax called this method?

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have created one web service that will may called from web using jQuery ajax call or may call from desktop application that I have created

**I want to know in that webservice method.. Is this ajax call or not?..**

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: A web service  method called two way..From website using jQuery ajax call and also from desktop application.. I just want to know that who called this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` server variable is set and equals to 'XMLHttpRequest', you can assume that the request was made via jQuery AJAX.

Comment: @Yank: This is your best bet but it's not 100%. Most Ajax libs set this header but custom code may not... And Desktop apps may not either.

Comment: jQuery sets this variable, and apparently OP wants to differentiate whether the request was made via jQuery or desktop application, and in that case this would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tatu Ulmanen answered you can check the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` server variable is set and equals to `'XMLHttpRequest'` to know that the request is ajax.

For this to work it is important that the correct header is set by you or the javascript library you are using. Otherwise there is no way to differentiate because ajax requests are normal `GET`  or `POST` requests