# any method to know if a page was called with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, security

Is there any way to know whether the page was called using AJAX or not?
We were using an additional variable sent with POST method, and I know about [http_x_requested_with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595688/is-ajax-called-this-method). But I've read somewhere on a security-related blog that both of them can be easily (?) hijacked.
So is there a secure method to know: was it an AJAX request or not?
Thanks!

Comment: *"I've read somewhere on a security-related blog"*... can you provide the link or some more information? Are you accepting cross-domain requests? Yes, anything like `?is_ajax=1` is easily "faked" whether it is POST or GET. What are your specific concerns?

Comment: There is no secure way to detect an Ajax call. You can not provide security this way. You need to set up proper security through a login

Comment: @Pekka this sounds like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-requested-with` can easily be changed, client side.

...but the point of the header isn't to provide secure login information or session security, it's to figure out how to handle the incoming request.

If I send a `GET` request for `data.php`, without setting the header, then maybe I need to serve an XML file, or maybe I need to serve a whole HTML page with full-site functionality, which has a list or table of that data in user-readable format.

Meanwhile if the header is set, maybe I just send a JSON response so the client can refresh itself or load a new widget on the page.

None of this is meant to be secured, or to provide security.
That would be like tying videogame security to resolution/graphics settings.

If the client coerced a particular setting, and they couldn't handle the response, tough.

If the client coerced a setting, and you're giving them all kinds of sensitive data, just because they did, then that one is on you.

Comment: Actually, my main concern was that those pages are not well-designed. So if you open them without AJAX, they will be "naked".

Comment: @MenelionElensúle  Right, well, that's the benefit of checking. If you have access to the server's scripting language, you personally have the ability to decide how to serve the page, if it's missing the header.  `echo ($header_set ? $json_result : $html_result);` or just echo an empty string... Or whatever is appropriate. The point is that you decide what that is. And if they want to spoof a value, that's their loss, as long as you aren't giving away sensitive info (which you shouldn't do, even if it's a valid request).

Answer (score 0):

There is no secure way to detect an Ajax call. All requests can be spoofed. You can not provide security this way. You need to set up proper security, for example through a session-based login system.

Comment: I don't know that the OP means "secure" in the sense of "behind a login", but perhaps "a way that's guaranteed to work every time and cannot be spoofed" (in which case the answer is still probably no).

Comment: I think you misunderstood pekka's context. The answer doesn't directly imply session based login system as the solution. Rather, it gives a guide how a proper security system should be setup. Now, it depends on to OP how he/she wants to set it up because no one knows here what this ajax call will do.

Comment: Perhaps the OP believes that responses to ajax requests are "hidden" so to speak, and not accessible to prying eyes. In that case, this answer makes perfect sense. I asked the OP for clarification but received no response. @itachi

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually my main concern was to provide well-formed pages (that would fit in my website design), and if you open those up without AJAX, they will look terribly "naked". But thanks anyway for your security comments, since I was thinking whether there existed a secure way to do that. Of course we have a session-based login system :-).